# Using Python Great Expectations to remove invalid data

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, great-expectations

I just started with Great Expectations library and I want to know if it is possible to use it to remove invalidated data from Pandas DataFrame. And how I can do that if is possible ?
Also I want to insert invalid data to PostgreSQL database.

I didn't find anything about this in the documentation and on searching the Web.

Later Edit :
To clarify: I need that in the case great expectation for example find 5 rows in a DataFrame that are invalid (for example df.expect_column_values_to_not_be_null('age') has 5 rows with null) to remove them from original DataFrame and  insert them in a PostgreSQL errors table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Great Expectations` is a powerful tool to validate data.
Like all powerful tools, it's not that straightforward.

You can start from here:

```
import great_expectations as ge
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
    
# get some random numbers and create a pandas df
df_raw = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

# initialize a "great_expectations" df 
df = ge.from_pandas(df_raw)

# search for invalidate data on column 'A'. 
# In this case, i'm looking for any null value from column 'A'.
df.expect_column_values_to_not_be_null('A')
```

Results:

```
{
  "exception_info": null,
  "expectation_config": {
    "expectation_type": "expect_column_values_to_not_be_null",
    "kwargs": {
      "column": "A",
      "result_format": "BASIC"
    },
    "meta": {}
  },
  "meta": {},
  "success": true,
  "result": {
    "element_count": 100,
    "unexpected_count": 0,
    "unexpected_percent": 0.0,
    "partial_unexpected_list": []
  }
}
```

Look at the response : good news !!!
There aren't `null` values in my df.
`"unexpected_count"` is equal to `0`

API Reference :
https://legacy.docs.greatexpectations.io/en/latest/autoapi/great_expectations/index.html

---

**EDIT:**
If you need simply to find some invalid values and split your df into:

1. Clean Dataframe
2. Dirty Dataframe

maybe you dont need `"great_expectations"`. you can use a function like this:

```
import pandas as pd

my_df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,1,2,3,0,1,1,5,2]})

def check_data_quality(dataframe):
    df = dataframe
    clean_df = df[df['A'].isin([1, 2])]
    dirty_df = df[df["A"].isin([1, 2]) == False]
    return {'clean': clean_df, 
            'dirty': dirty_df}

my_df_clean = check_data_quality(my_df)['clean']
my_df_dirty = check_data_quality(my_df)['dirty']
```

Comment: First thank you for the answer. I don't understand the example : Were no null values in the original df or great expectations erase nul lvalues form df ?  What I need is like this : great expectation finds 5 rows in df that were invalid and  I need a possibility to erase these rows from original df and insert them in a errors table

Comment: In my example "great expectations" is used to find if there are null values in the original df.  No replacements, no eliminations. "great expectations" is great to determine your data quality.

Comment: ok. I understand but is not exactly what I need. I need (from your example) to collect all rows that has null in any column , remove them form original df and insert collected rows in an errors table

Comment: have a look at this : https://legacy.docs.greatexpectations.io/en/latest/autoapi/great_expectations/expectations/core/expect_table_row_count_to_equal/index.html

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but I don't understand : How I can use this API ?  I don't know before how many rows have an expected problem. For example I have an expectation for column ('A' ) to hava only values "one"  and "two". I need to collect all rows that invalidate this rule, collect them in a separate (maybe) dataframe and delete them from original dataframe

Comment: To do this, you don't need a complex tool like "Great Expectations". I edited my answer to your specific case.